# How to stop a uitextview from covering uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

So I have a UIView over a UITableViewCell in a tableview. I believe this UIView would be the headerView of this table.

inside this headerView I have a UITextview and am setting its intrinsic size to placeholder so It could grow with its content. I've also set the headerView's intrinsic size to placeholder for the same reason. now the problem am facing is that when the UITextView is getting big, it's starting to hide the tableview cells.

[image]

Comment: What are you doing to increase the size of the text view? Do you have it set up so it grows automatically as you type, or do you increase it "manually" in code? Is it non-scrolling?

Comment: yeah as I mentioned above (I have a UITextview and am setting its intrinsic size to placeholder so It could grow with its content.) so it grows automatically according to its content.

Comment: I can't get my text view to grow when I type in it after setting it up like you said in your question. Do you have scrolling off? What constraints did you give it to its superview? Did you do anything with the superview other than set its intrinsic content size to placeholder?

Comment: I am just using it to display text so I took off (editable,selectable and scrollingEnabled). it doesn't have any constraints with the superview. its constraints are with the objects above it like [leading to img] [top space to armour ][trailing to img]. I didn't do anything to the superView. If what am doing is wrong, what could be the correct way of doing this !

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it, that's why I was trying to reproduce the problem. One thing I've done when expanding a header view is to reset the view as the table's header after you do the expansion ( self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView). So, you  can try that line after you set the text view's text.

Comment: It's just not working.Nothing has changed when I did "self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView" :/ I appreciate your effort trying to help !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the size of the text view and return that in an override of intrinsicContentSize, and then use systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: to resize the header view. The text view needs to be pinned to the top and bottom of the cell (if you have views above the text view, it can be pinned to those instead, but those views then need to be pinned to the top of the cell). In my test app, I didn't do anything with the Intrinsic Size setting in IB I left it as system defined. I subclassed the text view and added this code,

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    CGRect textRect = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font} context:nil];
    return CGSizeMake(textRect.size.width, textRect.size.height + self.textContainerInset.top + self.textContainerInset.bottom);
}
```

In the table view controller, I did the following to see the header expand when I set new text,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Black",@"Brown",@"Red",@"Orange",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Blue",@"Violet",@"Gray",@"White"];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.header;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}


-(void)doStuff {
    self.tv.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. jfhk gdkj gkf fjkd jkgjhjh khj khkjhk kjh jkhjkh kjhkjhkjh  The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog. The end";
    CGSize headerSize = [self.header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, headerSize.width, headerSize.height);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.header;
}
```

When I initially setup the constraints in IB, the system gave me a warning, and suggested several things to change -- I only needed to change the vertical content compression resistance priority to 749 (from 750). I uploaded a test app here, http://jmp.sh/fLZv7XK