# Expanding UIView as UILabel inside grows

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xib

I have a `UIView` which is a superview of `UIImageView` and `UILabel`. UILabel can have different size depending on the amount of text in it. So, I need the `UIView` to grow and shrink together with the `UILabel` but can not make it working.

The screenshot of how it looks is below:

[image]

As you can see the spacing above and below of the label are too big. In the `.xib` I set up top and bottom constraints on the `UILabel` to be just `10` but apparently these are somehow violated. `UIView` has top constraint to the frame above with the image as `>=10`, so that it could grow from `10`.

You can see `.xib` below:

[image]

I tried to increase `Content Hugging Priority` of the `UIView` but it does not help. `UILabel` has just 4 constraints: top, bottom, left, right relative to its superview `UIView`. I have also tried to change `Content Hugging Priority` of `UILabel` relative to `UIView` but no success. The `UIImageView` is the actual border of the `UIView` that is shown in the picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change uiview's height using auto layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089195/how-to-change-uiviews-height-using-auto-layout)

Comment: It is rather specific in my case. I tried to play with the `placeholder` property but it is not helpful.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29482159/341994 along with my answer and the linked github project (which solves the problem entirely using constraints).

Answer (score 6):

Think you're missing:

View:

- Constraint: Height >= 20

Label:

- Lines: 0
- Constraint: Top and bottom margins to the (super) View
- Constraint: Height >= 10

Screenshot of a working example:

[image]

Tip: use the preview

Comment: Nice and Neat Explanation! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

So, in my case the solution was to set constraints of `UILabel` relative to the `UIImageView` and then set the `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to `250`. Then everything started to work. Thank you `matt`! I opened your `github` project and found that `Content Compression Resistance Priority` of `UIImageView` should be `250` - this was crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label to .sizeToFit(), or in InterfaceBilder the number of lines to 0, and either you set the max width (prefererred width) or make >=/<= constraints. As my experience, you have to play a bit with constraints to make it work, the preview in assistant editor is very useful in that case. Then you can set the width/height of the superviews to be the same as the label and some to make it bigger. Hope this works.

Comment: Still not successful, nothing changes.

Comment: Where is `sizeToFit` property?

Comment: Sorry, this is a function, myLabel.sizeToFit()